# infopath new form in Start page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have infopath browser based new form for a list. How can i display this newform in Startpage so that the user can fill the form from the startpage..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your page, and add a InfoPath form web part. You can find it under the folder **Forms** when choosing from the webparts.

Edit the webpart and choose the list where you created your original form. Select what view you wanna show and what the submit behavior should be and save the page.